# How to get all integers before hyphen from java String

Tags: java, regex

I want to parse through hyphen, the answer should be 0 0 1 (integer), what could be the best way to parse in java

```
public static String  str ="[0-S1|0-S2|1-S3, 1-S1|0-S2|0-S3, 0-S1|1-S2|0-S3]";
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Please provide us with the things you have tried so far to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: i tried something String[] parts=str.split["-"] etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below regex with Pattern and matcher classes.

```
Pattern.compile("\\d+(?=-)");
```

`\\d+` - Matches one or more digits. `+` repeats the previous token `\\d` (*which matches a digit character*) one or more times.

`(?=-)` - Only if it's followed by an hyphen. `(?=-)` Called positive lookahead assertion which asserts that the match must be followed by an `-` symbol.

```
String str ="[0-S1|0-S2|1-S3, 1-S1|0-S2|0-S3, 0-S1|1-S2|0-S3]";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?=-)").matcher(str);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: can you detail it, i am just new in java.

Answer (score 0):

one lazy way: if you already know the pattern of the string, use substring and indexof to locate your word.

```
String str ="[0-S1|0-S2|1-S3, 1-S1|0-S2|0-S3, 0-S1|1-S2|0-S3]";
integer int1 = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(str.indexOf("["),str.indexOf("-S1")));
```

and so on.